# Clear Android Edit Text inside a listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-edittext

I have a edit text and a Save button inside my list view. I have to clear the text when the user clicks the save button. I have tried  like

```
txtDescription.setText("");
```

But not worked. Any one know why it is not worked ? The Adapter class is attached

Please Help Me, Thanks in Advance!!

```
private class ListAdapters extends ArrayAdapter<ApplicationBean> {
    private ArrayList<ApplicationBean> items;
    private int position;

    public ListAdapters(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            ArrayList<ApplicationBean> mTitleList) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, mTitleList);
        this.items = mTitleList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        this.position = position;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.applicationlistitem, null);
        }

        final ApplicationBean o = (ApplicationBean) items.get(position);

        if (o != null) {

            txtDescription = (EditText) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.description_text);



            submitButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.submit_btn);
            submitButton.setTag(position);
            submitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                        PostRequest p = new PostRequest(Integer.parseInt(v
                                .getTag().toString()));
                        p.execute();
                }

            });
        }
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return items.size();
    }

}



private class PostRequest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    ProgressDialog dlgprogress;
    int position;

    public PostRequest(int selectedIndex) {
        position = selectedIndex;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        dlgprogress.dismiss();
        final Dialog dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)
                .setTitle("Message")
                .setMessage(result)
                .setPositiveButton("Ok",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int whichButton) {
                                dlgprogress.dismiss();
                                dlgprogress.cancel();
                                txtDescription.setText("");
                            }
                        }).create();
        dlg.show();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dlgprogress = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, "", "Please wait");
        // dlgprogress.show(mContext, "", "Please wait");
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        //do something.............
        //..........................
        dlgprogress.dismiss();
        return rsponse;
    }

}
```

applicationlistitem.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#FFFFFF">



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lineatlayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="DESCRIPTION : "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/description_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" 
            android:textColor="#000000">
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SUBMIT" />

   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Show your possible code of your listview and if custom adapter.

Comment: my que is you have multiple edit text in list view? if yes then put your code here you got ans quickly.

Comment: please add code of applicationlistitem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also set any `object` as TAG to your button view.

So do it like this in your `getView()` method and I supppose it will work.

```
             //EDIT
         txtDescription.setTag(position); // set position to edittext

         submitButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.submit_btn);
         submitButton.setTag(txtDescription); // set the current edittext object 

         submitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {        
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                       EditText tv = (EditText)v.getTag(); // get edittext object
                       tv.setText("");
                             //Edit
                       PostRequest p = new PostRequest(Integer.parseInt(tv
                                .getTag().toString())); // get position from edittext
                    }
                });
```

**EDIT TO SEND Complete View**

I have not tested this, but I suppose it will work if don't work then also send the Checkbox to constructor as you send editext.

```
class PostTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{
    CheckBox cb;
    EditText et;
    int pos;
    PostTask(int pos,View view)
    {
        cb = view.findViewById(R.id.cbox1);
        et = view.findViewById(R.id.et1);
        pos = Integer.parseInt(et.getTag().toString());
    }
}
```

//Now in getView change

```
submitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {     
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                   PostRequest p = new PostRequest((View)v.getParent()); // get position from edittext
            }
 });
```

Comment: App crashed......10-31 11:34:14.141: E/AndroidRuntime(1226): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText

Comment: @user1767260 The error says that you have setTag(position) and trying to get EditText with getTag()... so please check that you have correctly written this line `submitButton.setTag(txtDescription);` and remove the line where you have set position as tag.

Comment: I can't set submitButton.setTag(txtDescription); as I have to pass the position to PostRequest

Comment: Okay I understand, look we can only set one object as TAG to a view so..you can do it like this way as I shown in Edit..I added two lines check those. @user1767260

Comment: Thanks worked.If I want to clear the description in onPostExecute of PostRequest?

Comment: Two Ways 1. Send edittext object to AsyncTask in constructor with position (this is better option\)
2.Make one Global edittext object and assigned tv to it in onClick and clear in onPostExecute.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and time :). One more doubt. If I have a checkbox there and I have to clear it also on onPostExecute?

Answer (score 2):

Maintain the custom adapter class for the listview

```
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row=null;
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater=cntx.getLayoutInflater();
        row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_list_item, null);

        EditText txtDescription=    (EditText)row.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
        Button Savebtn  =   (Button)row.findViewById(R.id.SaveBtn);

        Savebtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                txtDescription.setText("");
                // And your additional coding
            }
        });
   }
```

If you are new to custom adapter for the listview check [here](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429)

Comment: I doubt that it will work, still I will implement once, but I wish you also scroll the listview and then try check that if it work or not. [My assumption is that the last object assigned to txtDescription will always be setText("") not the one you click]

Answer (score 0):

You got editText and submit button on every list item??

All right, listView has the system that converts views... It does not create view as much as your array's size, but only creates enough to show user on screen then it starts convert them however you want while you're scrolling... so if you clear one editText, you can see it filled with some other's value... So i would recommend you to have another array to feed your listView, like you save your editText value and on submit button click you delete them and on adapter you should set editText's text with this array, so it'll be empty if the value's already submitted.

And here is a solution for your issue:

Try to have an array same sized with your list:

```
ArrayList<String> texts = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
texts.add(“”);
```

so all of your editTexts will be empty at first...
Then you set them on your getView method in your custom adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    this.position = position;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.applicationlistitem, null);
    }

    final ApplicationBean o = (ApplicationBean) items.get(position);

    if (o != null) {

        txtDescription = (EditText) v
                .findViewById(R.id.description_text);

    // you should set your every views’ editText here
    txtDescription.setText(texts.get(position));

    // here you save texts also they changes
    txtDescription.addTextChangedListener({
         @Override
         public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            texts.remove(position);
            texts.add(position, s.toString());
         }

         @Override
         public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) { }

         @Override
         public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) { }
     });

        submitButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.submit_btn);
        submitButton.setTag(position);
        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
        texts.remove(position);
        texts.add(position, “”);

                    PostRequest p = new PostRequest(Integer.parseInt(v
                            .getTag().toString()));
                    p.execute();
            }

        });
    }
    return v;
}
```